# SMplayer video filter for changing non-YouTube resolution?

Tags: display-resolution, video-streaming, smplayer

*I asked for help at SMplayer-forum, but the response probably won't be quick, so I paste the question below:*

Hi! New forum member.

My operating system on a Dell Inspiron 910 is Xubuntu 16.04, my SMplayer *Menu>About* gives:
Version: 17.8.0 (revision 8621)
Using Qt 4.8.7 (compiled with Qt 4.8.7)
Using MPV 0.14.0

I cannot change resolution in some Live Broadcast URLs that don' t come from YouTube, I hope this is because I don' t know how to pass *options and filters to MPlayer/mpv*, if not then it is not possibile to reduce these Live Broadcast resolutions.

I go to https://www.rt.com/on-air/ and I click the **HD** button on the video frame, I change to **360p**. Then I click the *share* icon on the top-right of the video frame and click the *URL* icon to copy it. Sadly I just copy the generic video URL, without any **360p** resolution filter...
 I have set *Preferences>Network>YouTube(and other sites)* to *Auto* and *360p (mp4)*, but this does not affect the resolution obviusly because it is not a YouTube stream... So I belive I have to pass some video filter. I wonder if I sould better pass this filter to *View>Information and properties>Options for MPlayer/mpv*, in order to pass it only to the specific URL.

Any help?

I would also like to know if it is possibile to pull the subtitles from YouTube videos, I admit I did not search the forum for that, for the previous problem I did but I found no useful information.

Thanks in advance!

*Thanks in advance also **askubuntu** users!*

Comment: I thought people use SMplayer also for Live streaming on weak machines, so someone would have the answer for the video filters & options.